# Callins specific function depending on macro parameter in C

Tags: c, macros

I have multiple functions with very similar identifiers (func1(), func2(), func3(), ...) and i need to create a macro to call them all in one.

i already tried to use concatenation but i couldn't figure it out.

```c
void func1() {}
void func2() {}
void func3() {}

#define call(N) // here needs to go the code to call the N func like func#N()
```

so that later in the code i can do something like this:

```c
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        call(i);
}
```

if there are other methods that i don't know or you can do it in another way show me your ideas. if possible i'd like to stick with macros

Comment: Use the token pasting operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `N` is guaranteed to be a digit 1, 2, or 3, one could use

```
#define call(N) func##N()
```

but that could fail if `N` might have other forms.  If the only other possibility that needed to be accounted for would be that `N` could be a macro that would expand to a single digit, one could use:

```
#define do_call(N) func##N()
#define call(N) do_call(N)
```

Alternatively, one could allow for `N` being computed in arbitrary fashion if the code were written as:

```
void (*const funcs[3])(void) = {func1, func2, func3};

void call(int n)
{
    funcs[n-1]();
}
```

If the functions return a value or take parameters, replace the leading `void` with the return type and/or replace `(void)` with a parameter list.  This approach would work even if the value `N` is a complex expression or may not be known until runtime.

Comment: good idea i'm just working on it give me some time. now is night here i'll post result next day

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the concatenation operator (`##`)

```
#define call(N) call##N()
```

It's unclear why this would be necessary though - why not just type call1() instead of call(1). This won't help with dynamically selecting the right function to call based on a variable. For that you'd need conditional logic.

```
switch (n) {
    case 1: call1(); break;
    case 2: call2(); break;
    default: ...; break;
}
```

Comment: yes i forgot to put a pice in the post now is updated

Comment: until now i've used the switch but i wanted to avoid long portions of code

Comment: I see, so in that case perhaps define a function `call` that implements a `switch` as above or `if/else` to call the right underlying function based on the runtime value of the argument.